# Launch Octave with GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface, octave

I downloaded octave version 4.2.1 as instructed here http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_macOS, and I am able to run Octave from the terminal. However, I cannot launch Octave using GUI. When I add the command `--force-gui`, nothing happens.

I have tried `brew reinstall octave --with-qt --with-fltk --with-gui`
, which does not help.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have qt4 installed?

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/15986

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
Tried qt, flk but nothing happens with homebrew.

I do this:

- Remove octave from homebrew : `brew uninstall octave`
- Installed MacPort (https://guide.macports.org)
- Install octave by macport :  `sudo port install octave`

Answer (score 1):

The repository homebrew/science is dead. Now Octave is available on dpo/homebrew-openblas

Just type:

```
brew tap dpo/openblas
```

Next pin the repository:

```
brew tap-pin dpo/openblas
```

Then install the dev snapshot with Java and the GUI

```
 brew install dpo/openblas/octave --HEAD --with-qt --devel --with-java
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also install Octave via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) by executing

```
sudo port install octave
```

in the terminal. By default MacPorts will install Octave with the following options: +accelerate +app +docs +gfortran +graphicsmagick +qt5 +sound +sundials. It is qt5, that is necessary for the GUI backend. To view available options prior the installation you may execute:

```
port variants octave
```

To install Octave with the options you like list the options at the end of the command:

```
sudo port install octave +atlas +gcc10
```

Finally, to view the options with which Octave was installed, execute:

```
port installed | grep octave
```

And to launch Octave with GUI run:

```
octave --gui &
```